# confirm box, then with input box and verify the content

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is it possible achieve following sequence of actions with simple comfirm, prompt in jsp  and get the value and return to the main page for next action?

sequence actions:  click cancel link ->confirm box popup -> promp box for additional info -> click ok button and main page gets the input text and pass on to cancel function.

This is what I have so far, but it seems buggy, but I don't know if I will have to use div for this.

Greatly appreciated!

```
<a class="action" href="manualCancel?obj={{objectId}}&cancel={{cancelInfo}}" onclick="return createCancel('cancel this ({{ objectId }})')">Cancel</a>


function createCancel(action) {
    ret = confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + '?')
    if (ret) {
        var cancelInfo;
        do {
            cancelInfo = prompt('Please provide valid cancel reason', '');
        }
        while(cancelInfo.length < 4){
            dim()
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `location.href`

```
<a class="action" href="#" onclick="createCancel('cancel this ({{ objectId }})')">Cancel</a>


function createCancel(action) {
    ret = confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + '?')
    if (ret) {
        var cancelInfo;
        do {
            cancelInfo = prompt('Please provide valid cancel reason', '');
        }
        while(cancelInfo.length < 4){
            dim()
        }
        location.href = 'manualCancel?obj={{objectId}}&cancel=' + cancelInfo;
    }
}
```